# How do I make only one class div element changeable, so that if one is clicked, others can't be? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to make a rating system, so that only one div at a time can be changed, but all of them can still be clicked.

```js
const number = document.getElementsByClassName('number');

function changeColor(arg) {
  arg.addEventListener('click', () => {
    arg.style.backgroundColor = 'hsl(216, 12%, 54%)';
    arg.style.color = 'white';
  })
}


for (let i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
  changeColor(number[i]);
}
```

```html
<div class="number icon"><h2>1</h2></div>
<div class="number icon"><h2>2</h2></div>
<div class="number icon"><h2>3</h2></div>
<div class="number icon"><h2>4</h2></div>
<div class="number icon"><h2>5</h2></div>
```

I figured out how to make class elements changeable on click with a loop, but now they can all be changed which isn't what I want. I found some similar answers but they are in jQuery which I unfortunately don't know yet.

Comment: can you create a snippet to reproduce the problem that you have?

Comment: @ChrisG Well this is the whole code for this particular task, so I don't have anything else to show haha. The problem is actually logical since I don't know how to make it so that only one div can be changed when clicked, e.g. when you click 3 and then 4, 3 returns to normal and 4 remains changed. Right now I can click them all sequentially and they will all change.

Comment: @Dejan "create a snippet" refers to "please format your code as a runnable snippet", like jsfiddle offers; jjj also did use the snippet formatting in their answer. It would've helped if Chris linked [this howto here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do), seeing that you're a new user... also, Gabriele already edited the question for you, it is now a snippet.

Comment: `<h2>` is a strange element to apply to a… list item?

Comment: @user3840170 Seems OP is still learning the ropes, misusing a headline tag to quickly make some text big is acceptable in my book when experimenting without experience. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to reset the other number when a new number is selected. Added a `resetAll()` function before the new number is highlighted.

```js
const number = document.getElementsByClassName('number');

function changeColor(arg) { 
     arg.addEventListener('click', () => {
     
        resetAll();
     
        arg.style.backgroundColor = 'hsl(216, 12%, 54%)';
        arg.style.color = 'white';
     })
}

function resetAll () {
  for(let i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        number[i].style.backgroundColor = 'unset';
        number[i].style.color = 'unset';
  }
}


for(let i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    changeColor(number[i]);
}
```

```html
<div class="number icon"><h2>1</h2></div>
<div class="number icon"><h2>2</h2></div>
<div class="number icon"><h2>3</h2></div>
<div class="number icon"><h2>4</h2></div>
<div class="number icon"><h2>5</h2></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

On each click, you need to reset the styles on all *other* elements than the clicked one. It's easier to just reset them all first, then set your "it is selected" style on the clicked element.

In this code, I used black on white as "not selected", you'll need to adapt that.

```
const number = document.getElementsByClassName('number');

function changeColor(arg) { 
     arg.addEventListener('click', () => {

        for(let i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            number[i].style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
            number[i].style.color = "#000";
        } 
        arg.style.backgroundColor = 'hsl(216, 12%, 54%)';
        arg.style.color = 'white';
     })
}


for(let i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    changeColor(number[i]);
}
```

Generally, I'd advise not to set styles directly, but add or remove CSS classes. This way, you can set both styles (selected and not selected) via CSS.